# How can i write query record in table have parentID with condition parentID == 0 and ID != (parentID)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Here i my LINQ query to get record in Table Menu with condition are parentID == 0(get root menu) and ID != (parentID list) (which is parent ID list is are id of menu record that have child), i just want to load all record includes root menu that have no children record and children record :

```
List<Menu> menus = MenuDAO.Instance.GetAll(); // Get All Record in Menu Table
var parentID = (from p in menus where p.ParentID != 0 select new {p.ParentID}).Distinct(); // Get unique ParentID in Menu Table
        List<int> numParentID = new List<int>();
        foreach (var a in parentID)
        {
            numParentID.Add(a.ParentID);
        } // assign to a list <int>
        this.ddlMenu.DataSource = from m1 in menus
                                  where !(numParentID).Contains((int)m1.ID) && m1.ParentID == 0
                                  select new { m1.ID, m1.Name };
        this.ddlMenu.Databind();
```

And i run this code , i display record that have no children, do not display chilren record. Somebody help me fix it. My new in LINQ , thanks a lot.

The Result as i expect here is : **list of record that do not have any children**, my Menu table schema is : ID, Name, Order, ParentID.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions

1-You don't need to select an anonymous object in the first select, you could write as

```
var parentIDs = (from p in menus 
                 where p.ParentID != 0 
                 select p.ParentID).Distinct();
```

always a good practice to name collections as plural (`parentIDs`)

2-No need to iterate to create a `new List<>`, so you can write all of them in one query

```
  List<int> numParentIDs = (from p in menus 
                            where p.ParentID != 0 
                            select p.ParentID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer : 
first select all the leaf level children IDs. Get all ID except the values in the ParentID column. And then do a select from menu by joining the leafIDs

```
var leafMenuIDs = menus
                    .Select(m => m.ID)
                    .Except(menus.Select(m => m.ParentID).Distinct())                                         
                    .Distinct();


 this.ddlMenu.DataSource = from m in menus
                           join id in leafMenuIDs on m.ID equals id
                           select new { m.ID, m.Name };
```

Comment: i edited my post and The Result as i expect here is : list of record that do not have any children, my Menu table schema is : ID, Name, Order, ParentID. thank you

Comment: Hi nasmifive, i write my code base on your answer but i got a error :
at Except operator is : System.collections.generic.IEnumberable<long> does not contains a definition for 'Except' and the best method overload 'System.LINQ.queryable.Except<TSource>(System.LINQ.IQueryalbe<TSource>, System.collections.generic.IEnumberable<Tsource>)' has some invalid arguments
i do not know how to fix it, could you give me a suggestion. thanks so much

Comment: in addition, ID column Type is long