# How to fix this LINQ Error

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The Result as i expect here is : list of record that do not have any children, my Menu table schema is : ID (long), Name(string), Order(int), ParentID (long)

first select all the leaf level children IDs. Get all ID except the values in the ParentID column. And then do a select from menu by joining the leafIDs

here my code :

```
var leafMenuIDs = menus
                .Select(m => m.ID)
                .Except(menus.Select(m => m.ParentID).Distinct())                                         
                .Distinct();


this.ddlMenu.DataSource = from m in menus
                       join id in leafMenuIDs on m.ID equals id
                       select new { m.ID, m.Name };
```

i got a error : at Except operator is :

> `System.collections.generic.IEnumberable<long>` does not contains a definition for 'Except' and the best method overload `System.LINQ.queryable.Except<TSource>(System.LINQ.IQueryalbe<TSource>, System.collections.generic.IEnumberable<Tsource>)` has some invalid arguments .

please help me fix this error. thanks a lot

Comment: You should have continued this question under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483184/how-can-i-write-query-record-in-table-have-parentid-with-condition-parentid-0/5484505#5484505. Duplicating might benefit you but others

Comment: I guest ID and ParentId are of same type (long), try the second select with different lambda alias menus.Select(x => x.ParentID).Distinct() as Mvision suggested

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
var items = from m in menus
            where !menus.Where(c => c.ParentID == m.ID).Any() 
            select new { 
                m.ID,
                m.Name};
```

Here you are selected every `menu` that doesn't have a `ParentID` referring back to it.

---

In response to comment by @mmix, here's the generated SQL (using Linqpad)

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name]
FROM [menus] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [menus] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ParentID] = ([t0].[ID])
    ))
```

Comment: shouldn't that be menus.ParentID == m.ID?

Comment: how does this "evaluate" to SQL? Will it go in a single trip?

Comment: @mmix - yes its a single query. Here's the generate SQL (using Linqpad) - `SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name]
FROM [Menus] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Menus] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ParentID] = ([t0].[ID])
    ))`

Comment: thank you guys, i'll try your suggestion , and feedback to you. thanks again.

Comment: @NevenHuynh - no problem, happy to help. You know you can accept the answer that solved your problem. (the tick on the left) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here might be that `m=>m.ID` & `m=>m.ParentID` are conflicting. 
Try changing it to `m=>m.ID` and `x=>x.ParentID` (different lambda expression names)